# syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Tags: drivers, wacom

I'm new to linux and I recently started using elementary OS. What is my problem?

I'm trying to instal my WacomOne tablet driver folowing the guide offered by "The Linux Wacom Project" from here: https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source .

What I did? I downloaded the files and now I'm trying to compile the code using the code given by them:

```
$ if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
```

But I get an error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

Do anyone have any idea why? Sorry if this is a silly question :(

Comment: If you are installing from the github sources use autogen.sh. If you downloaded a release tarball use ./configure . After that runs, type make and then sudo make install.

Comment: Your question is why do you have the mistake. I do not know the answer, but what I want to share is that I manage to run my wacom bamboo tablet using this: - First open the "Software & Updates" program and ensure the "Source code" box is enabled in the "Ubuntu Software" tab. Close the window and tell it to reload the software list if prompted. Next, install the dependencies by running:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential && sudo apt-get build-dep libwacom`    source - https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/wiki